# multiple testsuite in testng.xml not working inside jar

Tags: java, junit, testng

I have multiple test suite inside a jar, and I have created one main testng configuration file named testng.xml and added all suite in the xml file. Now if I am trying to run the testng.xml file using main method of jar using below code:

```
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setTestJar("test.jar");
tng.run();
```

The problem here is if I am trying to execute only one test suite using above mentioned method, it is working fine, but how can I execute multiple test suite using this way as I am getting exception `stream closed` once I try to load multiple test suite mentioned in testng.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run test suite by adding a class having main function as below :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    org.testng.TestNG.main(args);
}
```

Where arguments will be testNG arguments e.g.

> java -jar yourjar testng1.xml [testng2.xml testng3.xml ...]